# How to use the latest sinon in ui5?

Tags: sapui5

I am follow this guide to do Unit Test with QUnit and Sinon: [Step 28: Unit Test with QUnit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e1ce1de315994a02bf162f4b3b5a9f09)

Added sinon in `unitTest.qunit.html`:

```
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.sinon");
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.thirdparty.sinon-qunit");
```

It seems ui5 still use Sinon.JS v1.14.1:
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/thirdparty/sinon.js

Latest sinon is already v4.1.2: http://sinonjs.org/releases/

So how to `require` the latest sinon?

Because our pipeline use sinon v4.1.2, so function like `var stub = sinon.stub(object, "method", func);`is duplicated. But I can not use `stub(obj, 'meth').callsFake(fn)` in my ui5 project. http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/stubs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

integrate `sinon.JS v4.1.2` as a third party library into the ui5 application:

1. create a `sinon.js` file in your project.
2. copy paste the code of the `sinon.JS v4.1.2` into the sinon.js file.
3. put on the top of the `sinon.js` file a `jQuery.sap.declare("yourPath/sinon")`.
4. put into the `unitTests.qunit.html` a `jQuery.sap.require("yourPath/sinon")`.